# What is use of lifecyle property in insert bucket in Google Cloud Storage JSON API?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-apis-explorer

The insert bucket API for Google Cloud Storage allows setting bucket lifecycle. But a bucket lifecycle cannot be enabled unless you do a patch call. Also a patch call cannot be done unless a bucket exists. Let us say I am creating a new bucket then what is the purpose of having lifecycle field in insert? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new bucket and give that bucket a lifecycle configuration with the same call. Here's an example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=my-project-id
{
  "name": "my-lifecycle-test",
  "lifecycle": {
    "rule": [
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "Delete"
        },
        "condition": {
          "numNewerVersions": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
 "kind": "storage#bucket",
 "id": "my-lifecycle-test",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-lifecycle-test",
 "projectNumber": "1234567890",
 "name": "my-lifecycle-test",
 "timeCreated": "2018-08-17T16:13:04.553Z",
 "updated": "2018-08-17T16:13:04.553Z",
 "metageneration": "1",
 "location": "US",
 "lifecycle": {
  "rule": [
   {
    "action": {
     "type": "Delete"
    },
    "condition": {
     "numNewerVersions": 1
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 "storageClass": "STANDARD",
 "etag": "CAE="
}
```

You can try this out yourself with the "Try this API" tab in the documentation page for buckets.insert: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert

That said, even if you could not, buckets are usually only created infrequently, and new lifecycle policies also affect objects that were present before the lifcycle rules are set. If you're creating buckets and lifecycle rules so frequently that it's inconvenient to do such as two separate operations, it's possible that you're doing something suboptimal.